# How should I design a multi-purpose table?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

Let's suppose I have the following schema:

- Table A has a 0 to N relationship with table B
- Table B has a 0 to N relationship with table C
- Each item on A, B or C may have comments from multiple users (another table?).

A concrete example:

- Table Budgets may contain N Revisions
- Each Revision of the Budget may contain N items
- The users should be able to write a comment on the budget, on the revision, or on the item itself.

My take on this:

- Table A

  - `int Id`
- Table B

  - `int Id`
  - `int A_Id`  (foreign key)
- Table C

  - `int Id`
  - `int B_Id`  (foreign key)
- Table Comments

  - `int Id`
  - `int A_Id   allow null`
  - `int B_Id   allow null`
  - `int C_Id   allow null`
  - `varchar Text`

I feel this is not the best way to do it, because:

1. I have no guarantee at DB level that the Comments table will have no more than one foreign key
2. I have no guarantee at DB level that the Comments table will have at least one foreign key
3. This is a mess if I scaffold the context classes using a ORM like Entity Framework

FYI, this is just example code that represents the issue I'm facing. In my real project, I have at least 10 tables that will have comments. So, I want to avoid creating a Comment table for each other table (`Comments_A`, `Comments_B` and so on).

Is there a better way?

Comment: You can add constraints to guarantee 1. and 2.

Comment: some 'normal form' (i really do not have a clue which one ) 'demands' foreign keys, but it's not a MUST. So you could define a table with three fields a primary key ( tablename,id, text), where tablename refers to 'A' or 'B' or 'C', and id to the appropriate id, with combination of (tablename,id) being unique and primary key